# Change product price on order submit

Tags: event-observer

What is the best way to change ordered product price when the order is submitted, on sales_order_place_before or similar event.

Comment: Are you trying to change the price in the cart (which seems a bit shady), or what I expect is that you are trying to change the product that was purchased price for the next visitor?  Like, say, the first 10 people get it at this special price then it goes up and you want to auto change it on 10.  I just want to make sure I understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure the order has gone through, I would create an observer on sales_order_place_after.  That way, once the event is fired the order has been placed.   If you do it on sales_order_place_before, there's still a chance something happens and the order doesn't complete.